# Erlang. Can someone help me figure out why is throwing me that error when I try to run the program?

Tags: eclipse, erlang

[Can someone help me figure out why is throwing me that error when I try to run the program?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZLHR.gif)

Comment: Please, paste the whole code here (and the terminal output too) instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the module name is `lab06.erl`, so the function should be `lab06:hello_world().`

I don't know if the IDE does it automatically, but most likely you'll need to compile and load the code into the VM. You can do that with `c(lab06).` (the file should be reachable from the code path, though).